# Get the next span with class

Tags: jquery

I have the following Html structure for every `<select>` object in my page:

```
<div class="clsPropertyDiv clsPropertyId_16 ">
        <span class="inputTitle">You can select multiple items</span><br>
        <select id="select_16" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">
            <option class="" value="2699" id="opt_2699">Rusian </option>
            <option class="clsOptionSelected" value="2700" id="opt_2700">English </option> // take this text
            <option class="" value="2702" id="opt_2702">Hebrew</option>
        </select>

        <div class="ms-parent  multipleSelection" multiple="multiple">
            <button type="button" class="ms-choice">
                <span class="spnMulti"></span> // insert here.
                <div class=""></div>
            </button>         
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need to  get the selected  text and insert it to: `<span class="spnMulti"></span>`

This is what I was trying to do:

```
$('.selectOptions option').each(function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass('clsOptionSelected') {
                var selectedText = $(this).text();
                $(this).next('.spnMulti').text("selectedText ");

            }
        });
```

Comment: Remove quotes around `selectedText` - `$(this).closest('.spnMulti').text(selectedText);`

Comment: [If you'd read the docs on `closest` you'd understand that it doesn't do what you're attempting to do](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .spnMulti don't are childen of selectOptions. You need call the parent div and after find by spnMulti.

Example:

```
$(this).closest('.clsPropertyDiv').find('.spnMulti').text(selectedText);
```

and add class to select "selectOptions", in selector, you use: "$('.selectOptions option')" and not have a .selectOptions class in select.